# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key are incompatible

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I´m doing migrations in Laravel and this error happens when I proceed with the command `PHP artisan migrate`:

In Connection.php line 664:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'almacen_movimientos_user_id_foreign' are incompatible. (SQL: alter table `almacen_movimientos` add constraint `almacen_movimientos_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`
> ) on delete restrict)

In PDOStatement.php line 129:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'almacen_movimientos_user_id_foreign' are incompatible.

My migrations look like this:

almacen_movimientos table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('almacen_movimientos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
        $table->integer('cliente_proveedor_id');
        $table->integer('empresa_id');
        $table->integer('user_id');
        $table->enum('tipo' , ['ENTRADA' , 'SALIDA' , 'REUBICACION' , 'TRASPASO' , 'DEVOLUCION' , 'MSRO' , 'ENTRADA POR TRASPASO' , 'SALIDA POR TRASPASO'])->nullable();
        $table->string('referencia' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('observaciones' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_at');
        $table->timestamp('updated_at');
        $table->timestamp('deleted_at');
        $table->string('transportista' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('operador' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('procedencia' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->integer('almacen_id')->nullable();

        $table->foreign('cliente_proveedor_id')->references('id')->on('empresas')->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->foreign('empresa_id')->references('id')->on('empresas')->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->foreign('almacen_id')->references('id')->on('almacenes')->onDelete('restrict');
    });
}
```

Users Table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('id');
        $table->string('name' , 255);
        $table->string('apellido_paterno' , 115)->nullable();
        $table->string('apellido_materno' , 115)->nullable();
        $table->dateTime('fecha_nacimiento')->nullable();
        $table->string('telefono1' , 10)->nullable();
        $table->string('telefono2' , 10)->nullable();
        $table->string('calle' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('numero' , 45)->nullable();
        $table->string('colonia' , 255)->nullable();
        $table->string('codigo_postal' , 6)->nullable();
        $table->string('email' , 255)->unique();
        $table->string('user' , 20)->nullable()->unique();
        $table->string('password' , 255);
        $table->string('palabra_secreta' , 255);
        $table->string('remember_token' , 100)->nullable();
        $table->unsignedInteger('empresa_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('created_at');
        $table->timestamp('updated_at');
        $table->timestamp('deleted_at');

        $table->foreign('empresa_id')->references('id')->on('empresas')->onDelete('restrict');
    });
}
```

Can somebopdy tell me what am I doing wrong? I cannot fix this.

Thank you.

Regards.

Comment: The type of foreign key must be exactly the same with id which we want to refference to. In this case you have to change the foreign key columns type to unsignedBigInteger type.

Comment: And dont forget to run php artisan migrate:fresh to rebuild the entire tables.

Comment: Use this `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();`

Comment: Still shows the same error :(

Comment: ```$table->id(); //UNSIGNED BIG INTEGER``` so              ```$table->unsignedBigInteger('empresa_id')
```

Answer (score 65):

In `users` table you have defined primary key with id as unsigned bigint and in `almacen_movimientos` table the referenced `user_id` is defined as int

change

```
$table->integer('user_id');
```

to

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

The structure and data type of PRIMARY KEY and FOREIGN KEY must be same

Comment: @Rodri6uez  make sure you have same [**collations**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html) for both fields verify from database

Answer (score 6):

You can also solve in a more elegant way changing in yout schema of `almacen_movimientos` you should change:

```
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('restrict');
```

with

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('restrict');
```

Have a look at the documentation, you can do it from Laravel 7 on:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that foreign key data type is the same as its referencing column

Comment: Check also the encoding of your column if it is of type `VARCHAR` or similar.

Answer (score 4):

```
$table->increments('id')
```

use unsignedInteger in your foreign key

```
$table->id()
```

use unsignedBigInteger in your foreign Key

Comment: Please read [answer] and use more somber formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the dataType to resolve these issues.

```
public function up(){
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->string('body');
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->foreign('user_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('users')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
}
```

Noticed the local column ('id') was set to bigIncrements('id') and the foreign was set to Unsigned big integer.

Comment: Do this across your migrations file and make sure you create all locals before foreign. Eg, create users before products as user will be a foreigner in the kingdom of products.

Answer (score 0):

```
$table->integer('user_id');
$table->foreignId('user_id');
```

You Should Try *This* : -

```
$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).