# Laravel migration incompatible error happen. but both types seem to be compatible

Tags: laravel

Here is my DB and migration.php

I would like to set `category_id` as `foreign key` but incompatible error happens.

I don't know why it is incompatible. How Can I fix it?

```
mysql> desc category;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type         | char(1)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| order        | int          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
```

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('peaces', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id')->unique();
        $table->bigInteger('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->Integer('price');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('category_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('category');
    });
}
```

Exception trace:

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'category_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key constraint 'peaces_category_id_foreign' are incompatible.")

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY000\]: General error: 3780 Referencing column 'user\_id' and referenced column 'id' in foreign key are incompatible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63585525/sqlstatehy000-general-error-3780-referencing-column-user-id-and-referenced)

Answer (score 1):

I think in `category` table `category id` is `integer` but in `peaces` schema you have defined `category_id` as `big integer` so its throwing error .

So better update `category table` id as `big integer` to avoid error or visa versa

```
   Schema::create('category', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
```